# How to use AOP to intercept a method call in super on an argument?

Tags: java, aop

I'm extending a class and overriding a method. All I want to do is to call super, but with a modified argument that gets intercepted upon one of its methods is called. An example makes it more clear:

```
// Foo is an interface and also this method is part of an interface
@Override
public void foo(Foo foo) {
    // I want to intercept the call to foo.bar() in super
    super.foo(foo);
}
```

I'd rather use a tool that doesn't require a compiler of its own. What would be the optimal one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that `Foo` is an interface, you might consider using a [dynamic proxy](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html) that would:

1. Wrap the original foo
2. Intercept all message and forward them to the original foo

There is a complete [example](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html#examples) in the above link. Here is just the idea:

```
public class DebugProxy implements java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler {

   private Object obj;

   private DebugProxy(Object obj) {
      this.obj = obj;
   }

   public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args) throws Throwable
   {
       System.out.println("before method " + m.getName());
       return m.invoke(obj, args); 
   }
}

Foo original = ... ;
Foo wrapper = (Foo) java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
    original.getClass().getClassLoader(),
    original.getClass().getInterfaces(),
    new DebugProxy(original));
wrapper.bar(...);
```

Note that if `Foo` was not an interface, you could still subclass `Foo` and override all methods manually so as to forward them.

```
class SubFoo extends Foo
{
    Foo target;

    SubFoo( Foo target ) { this.target = target };

    public void method1() { target.method1(); }

    ...
}
```

It's pseudo-code, and I haven't tested it. In both cases, the wrapper allows you to intercept a call in `super`.

Of course, the wrapper has not the same class as the original `Foo`, so if super uses

1. reflection
2. `instanceof`
3. or access instance variables directly (not going through getter/setter)

, then it might be problematic.

Hope that I understood your problem right and that it helps.

Comment: This is it. I was thinking of way too difficult solution. Thanks for bringing me back to the ground level.