# issues when using spring aop load-time weaving deal with methods call inside itself

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-aop, load-time-weaving

I have bussiness class as follow:

```
class A {
    public void sayHello(String name){
        System.out.println("hello "+name);
    }
    public void openDoorForJack(){
        System.out.println("door opened");
        this.sayHello("Jack");
    }
}
```

and aspect class as follow:

```
@Aspect
class Aspect {
    @Pointcut("execution (* com..*.sayHello(String)) && args(name)")
    public void beforeSayHelloPointCut(String name) {}
    @Before("beforeSayHelloPointCut(name)")
    public void beforeSayHello(String name) throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(name+" is knocking");
    }
}
```

after I have all those beans configured in spring,I turn LTW on using

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>
<context:load-time-weaver aspectj-weaving="on" weaver-class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
```

of course aspectjrt,aspectj-weaver,spring-instrument are in position,-javaagent:path/spring-instrument.jar is passed to VM options and follow aop.xml is under META-INF

```
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC
        "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <!-- only weave classes in specific packages -->
        <include within="*"/>
    </weaver>

    <aspects>
        <!-- weave in just this aspect -->
        <aspect name="com.Aspect"/>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

When I run test like:

```
applicationContext.getBean(A.class).sayHello("Jack");
```

result seems perfect

```
Jack is knocking
Hello Jack
```

But when I run test that call sayHello inside itself

```
applicationContext.getBean(A.class).openDoorForJack();
```

no interception happens at all

```
door opened
Hello Jack
```

The reason way I use LTW is that I want methods call using "this" or "super" can be intercepted as well,but seems I failed to do so.
Would someone help me point out the problem,is there something I missed?

----------------------------EDIT---------------------------------
After some debug I found where I got wrong
In real life,
I hava "class A" under package **com.bussiness**
and "class Aspect" under package **com.aspect**
I worte aop.xml like follow

```
<weaver>
      <!-- only weave classes in specific packages -->
      <include within="com.aspect.*"/>
</weaver>
```

which is not correct,it should be the package that contains classes need to be woven,after I changed it to

```
<weaver>
      <!-- com package and its sub package all get woven-->
      <include within="com..*"/>
</weaver>
```

It finally work

Answer (score 0):

Try dynamic proxy, it should work. It's not easy but I think this is what you need.

More on this:
[How to use AOP to intercept a method call in super on an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646510/how-to-use-aop-to-intercept-a-method-call-in-super-on-an-argument)

Comment: yes,this way can also do the trick,consider it would do some side effects to "instanceof",I would put it as plan B